# <Web Scraping python> Extract data in class href tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I want to use python / beautifulsoup scrap this site :
http://www.ipeen.com.tw/search/all/000/0-100-0-0/%E4%B8%AD%E5%BC%8F/?adkw=%E5%8F%B0%E5%8C%97

Main question is how to extract "/shop/1057970-麻辣公館"
from html  like this :

```html
<h3 class="name" id="shop_h3_">
<a class="a37 ga_tracking" data-action="ad_shop" data-category="search" data-label="店名" href="/shop/1057970-麻辣公館" target="_blank">麻辣公館</a>
<span class="markVip">合作店家 <a class="joinVip ga_tracking" data-action="ad_shop" data-category="search" data-label="如何刊登" href="http://www.ipeen.com.tw/ad/adipeen.php?id=b31149405ef268fe0b2dd035f450000e">(如何刊登？)</a></span> </h3>
<div class="serPic">
<div class="align">
<span></span>
<a href="/shop/1057970-麻辣公館" target="_blank"><img alt="麻辣公館" class="lazy" src="http://iphoto.ipeen.com.tw/photo/ipeen/140x140/vip/0/7/9/store_1057970/sp1057970_20160416132749762.jpg" title="麻辣公館"/></a>
</div>
</div>
```

The one below is my code :

```js
url ='http://www.ipeen.com.tw/search/all/000/0-100-0-0/%E4%B8%AD%E5%BC%8F/?adkw=%E5%8F%B0%E5%8C%97'
opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
page = opener.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.find_all('a', {'class':"a37 ga_tracking"})
```

Please give some possible ideas
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on a good road. Just need to use:

```
soup.find('a', {'class':"a37 ga_tracking"})['href']
```

or, if You want more than one link:

```
[tag['href'] for tag in soup.find_all('a', {'class':"a37 ga_tracking"})]
```

Comment: hi @Fejs thanks for your response !
but only get  
```'javascript: void(0);'
```

while run 
```soup.find('a', {'class':"a37 ga_tracking"})['href']
```

Comment: maybe is sth like 
```soup.find_all('a', {'class':"a37 ga_tracking"})
```
?

Comment: but this one 
```[tag['href'] for tag in soup.find_all('a', {'class':"a37 ga_tracking"})]
```
works nice !
thanks ! @Fejs

Comment: `find_all` finds all occurrences, while `find` finds only first one. You can use `find` with `['href']` without list comprehension.